# Python web app getting valueerror 0 not in list

Tags: python-3.x, flask

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    tpopDloads = popDloads
    tpopShipped = popShipped
    locPopDload = []
    locPopShipped = []
    popDinfo = []
     popSinfo = []
    popDloadsOrd = sorted(tpopDloads, reverse=True)
    popShippedOrd = sorted(tpopShipped, reverse=True)
    for i in range(3):
        locPopDload.append(tpopDloads.index(popDloadsOrd[i]))
        popDinfo.append(dProducts[locPopDload[i]])
        tpopDloads[tpopDloads.index(popDloadsOrd[i])] = -1 #Problem line#

    for i in range(3):
        locPopShipped.append(tpopShipped.index(popShippedOrd[i]))
        popSinfo.append(sProducts[locPopShipped[i]])
        tpopShipped[tpopShipped.index(popDloadsOrd[i])] = -1

    return render_template('index.html', popDinfo=popDinfo, popSinfo=popSinfo)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
  File "/var/lib/openshift/5697165a0c1e66eb870000fb/app-root/runtime /repo/flaskapp.py", line 47, in index
tpopShipped[tpopShipped.index(popDloadsOrd[i])] = -1
ValueError: 0 is not in list
```

This is using two variable that are popDloads and popShipped which are both lists that contain a set of integers. I don't see why it's not working as it is trying to find the actual index of a number after the list has been ordered. It also works when the numbers are all zero, it's only after I change the numbers in another piece of code that I run into problems.

Comment: Your problem line is not where you indicate it: the error says `tpopShipped...`, which is a few lines below the line you commented. Please read more carefully, and (probably) copy-paste more carefully. You probably want to change `popDloadsOrd[i]` in that *actual* error line to `popShippedOrd[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you why your code isn't working. `0` isn't in the list `tpopShipped`.

```
>>> [1,2,3].index(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 0 is not in list
```